# Are normally distributed residuals that important when the magnitude is extremely small?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, residuals, linear

I have a data set for a linear regression in which the residuals are all less than 1% of the predicted value and R^2 is.993.

However, the residuals are not normally distributed. Does this this really matter? I used the equation for the line and plugged in additional measurements, and it is predictive within < 1%, which is within the range that I need.

Thank you!

Comment: That diagnostic really affects inference rather than predictions.  I would say so long as your residuals are symmetric and kinda look normal, you're fine.

Comment: Even an $R^2$ near 1 is consistent with residuals that point to a different functional form, a bigger deal than whether they are conditionally or marginally normal.

Answer (score 6):

Demetri Pananos makes a good point in his comment that I want to include in this answer.

"That diagnostic really affects inference rather than predictions."

So if all you care about is predictive ability and you have solid performance out-of-sample, you're fine.

However, if you're doing inference on the parameters in a way that assumes normal residuals, then you don't get out of needing normal residuals just because the numbers are small. Imagine the following conversation between physicists working on quantum mechanics and making tiny measurements.

**Marie**: "Ughhh, the regression isn't any good!"

**Niels**: "What's wrong?"

**Marie**: "The residuals aren't normal."

**Niels**: "Well then let's switch our units to light years so the numbers are really small."

The situation isn't really any different, except that now they have the fun of writing a lot of scientific notation to say how many light years across a proton is.